# Hibernate cascade delete две ссылки на объекты одного класса

Tags: java, hibernate

Имеются сущности :

Station:

```
package dev5.lavishek.trains.entity;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;
import org.hibernate.annotations.Cascade;
import org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType;

@Table
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
public class Station extends BaseEntity {

  @Column
  private String name;
  @OneToMany
  @Cascade(CascadeType.ALL)
  private List<Ride> rides = new ArrayList<>();

  public Station() {
  }

  @Builder
  public Station(Integer id, String name, List<Ride> rides) {
    super(id);
    this.name = name;
    this.rides = rides;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return
        super.toString() + "name='" + name + '\'';
  }

}
```

Ride:

```
package dev5.lavishek.trains.entity;


import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;
import org.hibernate.annotations.Cascade;
import org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType;

@Entity
@Table
@Getter
@Setter
public class Ride extends BaseEntity {

  @Cascade(CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE)
  @ManyToOne
  private Schedule schedule;
  @Cascade(CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE)
  @ManyToOne
  private Station stationFrom;
  @Cascade(CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE)
  @ManyToOne
  private Station stationTo;
  @Column
  private Double price;

  public Ride() {
  }

  @Builder
  public Ride(Integer id, Schedule schedule, Station stationFrom,
      Station stationTo, Double price) {
    super(id);
    this.schedule = schedule;
    this.stationFrom = stationFrom;
    this.stationTo = stationTo;
    this.price = price;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return super.toString() + "schedule=" + schedule +
        ", stationFrom=" + stationFrom +
        ", stationTo=" + stationTo;
  }
}
```

Как сделать , чтобы при удалении Station , удалялись все Ride , у которых была ссылка stationFrom или stationTo , на этот объект ?

Answer (score 0):

```
@OneToMany(orphanRemoval=true)
```

Hibernate удаляет дочерний объект, когда вы удаляете его связь с родительским объектом.